# data transfer between multiple fragments

Tags: java, android

I have an activity on which 4 fragments are loaded on it. But I want the data from first three fragments on 4th fragment. How can I do it ? I have used SharedPreferences for first three fragments to store the data. How can I get that SharedPreferenced key data on last fragment ?

// Register as: seller or buyer
// Personal details: Name, BirhtDate
// Address Details: total 5 fields
// Credentials: Email ID and Password
the data from fragments [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lANre.jpg),[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmgHG.jpg),[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ejT6M.jpg) should set on the [5]th fragment.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating

Comment: You can use ViewModel to transfer data between multiple fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You might do the wrong way... but for getting SharedPreferences values you need:

```
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

   sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    if(sharedPreferences == null)
        return;

   String data = sharedPreferences.getString(keyValue, defaultValue)
```

this is just an example, you didn't show any code...

Hope it helped you.